I can see the capacity tab in DevOps, but the capacity bars are not showing
I have the admin role, and am part of the sprint team. I can see the capacity tab in DevOps, but the capacity bars are not showing even though there are hours assigned to the tasks and work details is 'on'. All I see is an assigned to listing with a name and hours, but no bar. Can you advise how to make the bars show?
I checked my access level (admin), and licensing against the prerequisites and I have what it has listed.

Welcome! What tool are you using?

Azure DevOps is the tool.

I'm not sure how to post a screen shot to help explain the issue

@JoanAndrews You can refer to the steps in my answer to set the sprint capacity. Then you will see the capacity bar.

Thank you! That worked! :) Appreciate the help

I marked the answer as accepted


All I see is an assigned to listing with a name and hours,

Based on your description, the content you see in Sprints -> Work Details should look similar to the following:


Can you advise how to make the bars show?

To show the capacity bars in the Work details, you can refer to the following steps:
Step1: Navigate to Sprints -> Capacity and set the Capacity per day for each user.
For example:

Step2: You need to change the Sprint iteration to make sure that the current date is within the iteration interval.
For example: Current date 2024/8/27  | Iteration Range 2024/8/14 - 2024/8/31

Step3: You need set the work hours to Remaining Work field in work items.
Then you will see the capacity bars in the Sprints -> Work details.
Result:

For more  detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Adjust work to fit sprint capacity
